# C# - initialize variable inside method and use in whole class

Tags: c#, object-oriented

this is a conceptual question, but if i initialize a variable in c# as public will it be able to be used in the class as I want a variable "`player1`" and a variable "`player2`" where either could be one of the two (or more)

1. Player
2. Computer

Here is what i would like to know how I would do:

```
public class Game  
{   
    //equivalent of initializing it here
    public bool islogging;  
    public string[] log;  
    public int draws, round;  

    public Game(player p1, computer p2)  
    {  
        public player player1 = p1;  
        public computer player2 = p2;                                                           
    }
    //other overloads here...
    ...
}
```

trying this it doesn't work as the public keyword is rejected

```
public Game(player p1, player p2 )
{  
     public  player player1, player2;
     player player3 = p1;
     player player4 = p2;

 }
```

Comment: This isn't quite clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you try it instead of asking us.

Comment: I need to have a variable player 1 & 2 but depending on the way it's initialized it may be one of two types resulting in 4 potential outcomes pvp, pvpc, pcvpc and pcvp but if i were to use the var keyword i have to give it a starting value but that is impossible

Comment: So, your problem is that you don't know whether the argument being passed in is a Computer or Player?  What does your object hierarchy look like?

Comment: computer : player

Comment: The solutions to this are very simple, and almost any research into object oriented languages will teach you at least one solution. There are several.

Comment: @user181782 is this not what you are trying to do? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: I dont think it will. I'll just program them in different classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fundamental matter of scope.

Variables declared within a function are bound to the lifespan and accessibility of that function.<sup>*</sup>

C# doesn't allow you to declare variables that will persist as part of the class from within a function.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Lambda expression can sometimes invalidate that statement, but that's well outside the scope of what you're asking.</sub>

---

To accomplish what you're asking, use this syntax.

```
public class Game  
{   
    //equivalent of initializing it here
    public bool islogging;  
    public string[] log;  
    public int draws, round;  
    public player player1;
    public computer player2

    public Game(player p1, computer p2)  
    {  
        player1 = p1;  
        player2 = p2;                                                           
    }
    //other overloads here...
    ...
}
```

or you could also try the following.  But keep in mind that player1 and player2's scope will end with the constructor function.

```
public class Game  
{   
    //equivalent of initializing it here
    public bool islogging;  
    public string[] log;  
    public int draws, round;  
    public player player1;
    public computer player2

    public Game(player p1, computer p2)  
    {  
        player player1 = p1;  
        computer player2 = p2;                                                           
    }
    //other overloads here...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to do it in separate classes but thank you for letting me know

Comment: +1 To clarify the difference between the two it is often useful to put `this.player1 = p1;` when you are using instance fields, properties and methods of the class to show you're not using local variables.

Comment: user181782, your comment makes it sound like you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about declaring their type; the variables' types have to be known at compile-time, even before it knows which constructor it will use.

When declaring those variables, to be able to call the methods you'd like (Jump(), Move(), Die()) on both of them, you need to declare them as being the most-specific object type you know of them; but not SO specific that it will restrict you from declaring them as the opposite type. Here's an example:

```
Shape shape1;
Shape shape2;

shape1 = new Rectangle(); // This works, because a Rectangle extends off of Shape.
shape2 = new Circle(); // This also works, because a Circle extends off of Shape.
shape1 = new Circle(); // Now shape1 has been changed to be a circle, too. The original
// Rectangle just basically disappeared.
```

As for defining the classes "Shape", "Rectangle", and "Circle", like your "Player" class? Well, if all of this sounds new to you, you definitely need to read up on the concept of `Polymorphism`. I've given you kind of an abstract overview just to give you an idea of what it allows, but mainly it's meant to keep you from needing to copy-paste lots of code, or have large "if-is-type" or "if-is-state" checks of your objects.